# PHP not inserting data into MySQL table with correct SQL syntax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to insert a JSON array of objects passed via a jquery $.ajax POST into a MySQL database via PHP. I've seemingly tried everything but for some reason I can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$data = json_decode($_POST, true);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $worker_id = $item['worker_id'];
    $response_time = $item['time'];
    $video_id = $item['video_id'];
    $submission = $item['response'];
    $test_answer = $item['test_answer'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO nristudy (worker_id, response_time, video_id, submission, test_answer) 
    VALUES ('$worker_id', '$response_time', '$video_id', '$submission', '$test_answer')";

    if (!($conn->query($sql))) {
        die($conn->error);
    }

}

if (!$conn->commit()) {
    echo "Transaction commit failed";
    exit();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Javascript

```
var json = JSON.stringify(submissions);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://hci.cs.wisc.edu/nri/store_data.php",
    data: json,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Success: " + data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('An error occurred... look at the console for more information!');   
        console.log('jqXHR:');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log('textStatus:');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('errorThrown:');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: You may know this, or this may just be an exercise, but that code looks like it's wide-open vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Facing any errors? What happens? Let PHP do the dirty-work of checking for errors for you:  [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) -- or check your console-log to see if it's the JS failing you.

Comment: "I've seemingly tried everything" and "I can't get it to work" are not helpful at all. What specifically isn't working, and what specifically have you tried?  How do you know this "isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem depends heavily on what the error is. However, one thing that is pretty clear is that you should be escaping the strings you are trying to put into the query.

I recommend that you switch to using PDO and prepared statements as you will not have to worry about escaping anything and can rely on PDO to take care of it when you prepare the statement.

You might also want to try serialize instead of json_encode but if it works there is a chance that SQL injection is still a real big possibility for you.

Comment: Mysqli works just fine, OP just have to use prepared statements (which MySQLi supports). However, this isn't a solution as you said, so therfore this isn't really an answer.